# Работа с окнами в Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы при  нажатии на кнопку в окне, появлялось не новое окно, а лишь менялась нужная информация в том окне, в котором находилась сама кнопка. Вот на данный момент мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
def okno(x):
    d=["Введите своё имя", "Введите своё имя нормально!"]
    window=Tk()
    def get_click0():
        login=loginInput.get()
        symb=[']',']','>', '<',',','.','\\','/','{','}','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')',';',':',"'",'"',"№","?",'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        for i in login:
            if i==' ' or i in symb:
                c=1
                break
            else:
                c=0
        if c==1:
            okno(1)
        else:
            okno(0)
        print(c)
    window.title('Тест по истории')
    window.geometry('1920x1080')
    frame=Frame(window,bg='purple')
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    title=Label(frame,text=d[x], bg='white', font=100)
    title.pack()
    loginInput=Entry(frame,bg='purple',font=30)
    loginInput.pack()
    btn=Button(frame,text='клик', command=get_click0)
    btn.pack()
    window.mainloop()
okno(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменяйте параметры виджетов функцией `configure` или `config`, без разницы.
Пример на вашей кнопке:

```
btn.configure(text="Новый текст")
```